# Spotify's car mode on iOS devices

Tags: bluetooth, spotify

This is not programming question per se but something that I'm trying to figure out. How can Spotify know that I'm connected to my car's Bluetooth?

Since Spotify doesn't request any Bluetooth permissions on iOS, I guess that they don't use any Bluetooth scans to know what I'm connected to.

The other option that comes to mind is to use `AVAudioSession` framework.
It can give you the Bluetooth profile (A2DP, HFP, etc...) and it also gives you the name.
Many Bluetooth devices can be either A2DP or HFP so it doesn't mean it's a car. So, maybe Spotify uses the Bluetooth name to validate it?

To test this, I changed my headphones name to 'Toyota Touch' in my Bluetooth settings and when I opened Spotify, it was shown as if I was connected to a car.

Is this really how it works? It checks the name of the device and if it matches any car manufacturer than it says I am connected to a car? Maybe someone from Spotify can verify or disprove this?